# Change image or style of specific UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there any way that I can get a specific cell to change its style or background image while scrolling the table view?

I want to change the image of a cell which is on top of the visible cells. But only its image is going to be changed the others will stay same, until after scrolling the others come to top of the cells which are shown on the screen. Then the top one's image is going to change this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement `scrollViewDidScroll:` method of UIScrollViewDelegate in your controller then use `visibleCells` property of UITableView to get the visible cells of the table.

Something like the following code should work

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
 UITableView* tableView;
 NSArray* visibleCells;
 BOOL first;

 tableView = (UITableView*)scrollView;
 visibleCells = tableView.visibleCells;
 first = YES;
 for (UITableViewCell* cell in visibleCells) {
  if (first) {
   //customize the top cell
   first = NO;
  }else {
   //customize the other visible cells
  }
 }
}
```